# Flex add images to datagrid cell programmaticlaly

Tags: image, apache-flex, datagrid, tilelist

I have a flex application with a datagrid created dynamically. Also this datagrid is populated dynamically and some columns must show images.
The number of images in each cell is variable and depends on user selection.

I am not sure how I manage this. Should I assign an Item Renderer to those columns with a TileList and then add images to it when the user changes its selection? If so, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can manage it using a ItemRenderer with a TileList. then I pass the result data as a itemrenderer parameter. Thanks!